# How can I access a JButton on another file or class in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcomponent

I'm having a problem with JButton. I need to change the text on the goPauseButton when it has been clicked, but I get this error: `goPauseButton cannot be resolved`. I'm quite new to Java, so I started trying to solve the issue using techniques from other languages such as Free Pascal. There you need to refer to the class where the button is in, and then the button. In my code it would look like this:

```
PrisonersDilemma.goPauseButton.setText("Pause");
```

But then I get this error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field PrisonersDilemma.goPauseButton`

This is my code (so far), I've erased unimportant things:

Main class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.util.Hashtable;

//...

public class PrisonersDilemma /* possible extends... */ {
    // declaring
    JFrame frame;
    PlayingField field;
    JPanel componentPanel;
    public JButton goPauseButton;

    public JPanel createComponentPanel() {

        componentPanel = new JPanel();
        componentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,6));
        
        // set goPauseButton
        goPauseButton = new JButton("GO!");
        goPauseButton.addActionListener(field);
        goPauseButton.setBounds(110,350, 80,20); // first coordinates, then size
        frame.add(goPauseButton);

        return componentPanel;
    }

    void buildGUI() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                field = new PlayingField();

                // set frame
                frame = new JFrame("Prisoners Dilemma");
                frame.add(field);

                createComponentPanel();

                frame.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setLocation(200, 200);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                frame.setSize(400, 450);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }

        } );
    }
```

Class with ActionEventHandler

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class PlayingField extends JPanel 
                          implements ActionListener, 
                                     ChangeListener {
    
    private boolean started;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO
        if ("GO!".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            System.out.println("GO!");
            started = true;

            goPauseButton.setText("Pause"); // here is the error

        } else if ("Pause".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            System.out.println("Pause");
            started = false;
        } else if ("Reset".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            System.out.println("Reset");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code `goPauseButton` is a public instance property of the `PrisonersDilemma` class. You need an instance of this class to work with the `goPauseButton`. You can do this, but it would be much better if the `PrisonersDilemma` class keeps the `goPauseButton` private and provides a public method to change the button caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the way you're approaching the problem.  The `PlayingField` has no responsibility for modifying the state of the `goPauseButton` in `PrisonersDilemma`.  Instead, `PrisonersDilemma` should update the `goPauseButton` and call an appropriate method of `PlayingField`

For example...

```
goPauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        goPauseButton.setText("Pause");
        field.start();
    }
});
```

And...

```
public class PlayingField extends JPanel {

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("GO!");
        started = true;
    }

    public void pause() {
        started = false;
        System.out.println("Pause");
    }

    public void reset() {
        System.out.println("Reset");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Now I get this error: `The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})` in your very first line. Also `ActionListener` and `ActionEvent` "cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: You've imported `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` and `java.awt.event.ActionListener`?

Comment: That was dumb, I thought it was `java.swing.ActionEvent` and `java.swing.ActionListener`. Thanks!! Now I will try to adapt the rest of my code and see if it works.